# how are packets delivered from A to B in same subnet?

Tags: networking

Sorry, this is a basic question, but I was wondering what will happen in this case? Firstly, is the case below valid example?

Lets say I have 100 servers configured to be in same subnet. I want each of these servers to be able to communicate with one other. Let's say these servers are connected to some network switches. As an example --

```
                           ---- Switch 4 --- Server 3
                          /                   /
                         /      -------------/
                  --- Switch 3 /
                 /            /
                /            /
Server1 -- Switch 1 -- Switch 2 -- Server 2.
```

Based on what I read online, if the servers are within the same subnet, then there is no routing involved. The packets from server 1 are sent over the ethernet interface which says it belongs to this subnet and at the ethernet transport layer, and the frames are sent with the destination Mac set.

So, for the above diagram, if Server 1 wants to send a packet to Server 3, then it will determine that the packet needs to be sent down the interface that is associated with Switch 1. When Switch 1 tries to decide where to forward the packet, it realizes that frames with this particular MAC address should be forwarded to Switch 3 (not switch 2). Switch 3 then forwards to Switch 4 and Switch 4 then delivers it to Server 3.

Furthermore, my understanding is that, at the layer 2, no sophisticated routing algorithm is used by Switch 1 to decide whether it should send to Switch 2 or Switch 3. It is based on a dumb MAC table that tells it whether it has ever seen this MAC or Switch 2 or 3 and forwards accordingly.

Is my understanding above correct? If so, then what I fail to understand is this --

How is the above MAC based routing within same subnet, any better than using a layer 3 routing protocol like OSPF or LSP that seems to be a lot more smarter about routing efficiently.

If no routing algorithms are used, how will it realize that it is better to go via Switch 2 to reach Server 3 than use Switch 3?

Comment: "_How is the above MAC based routing within same subnet, any better than using a layer 3 routing protocol like OSPF or LSP that seems to be a lot more smarter about routing efficiently._" Routing is between networks, not in the same network. In the same network, you bridge, not route.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I now wonder how is it possible to have large subnets? As per discussion below, it's not recommended to have large subnets due to broadcast domain and are better of splitting it into smaller subnets and then use bridging in this small subnet.

Comment: You must bridge in the same network. We live in a layer-3 world. It used to be that you switch when you can and route when you must, but that is turned on its head today. The current best practices are to run layer-3 routing all the way down to the access switch. We no longer have applications that are required to be on the same network. Everything can be routed, and that fixes a lot of layer-2 problems, like broadcast storms. You are asking on the wrong SE site. [so] is for programming questions, not network questions.

Answer (score 0):

If no routing is present the path to the switch will be determine by its mac address. Server 3 must have 2 network cards (2 MACs' 2 IPS), one connected to switch4 and switch2. When you send a package you use the IP address, then an ARP broadcast will be made to get the MAC address of the device, once you have it then you create the packet with the appropriate headers (layer 2 Mac, layer3 IP).

If you have a routing protocol and instead of switches you have routers, different methods of cost can be taken into consideration to determine the fastest route. For example hoops and speed. You can even force the route via one path no mater what is the best one.

BONUS: If your switches have STP (spanning tree protocol) and have multiple connections between them, then they will determine the fastest route of connection between switches and have redundancy in case of one link fails. In this example the route may change on the diagram that you posted. But remember switches are connected between them with more than one connection 2 or more for each one of them.

Comment: If within a subnet I can never have routing, then why should I ever have a large subnet? Switching through a large network is much more expensive even with STP (which has issues) compared to just layer 3 routing isn’t it? Why is routing not possible within a subnet?

Comment: routing is possible with subnets. In fact in routing we subnet alot. Large networks are not a good idea because of the broadcast domain. A lot of devices sending broadcasts lower the overall speed of the network. Because of that we segment the networks with routers. STP does not have issues, most people does not understand how it works or have it miss configured. STP is used in large networks or high availability to provide redundancy.

Comment: Can a large LAN have more than 1 subnet then? Or you are suggesting I cannot have large LAN and would need to split it into smaller LANs with different subnets and put routers between them?

Comment: Isn't it better to use ECMP than STP to provide redundancy?

Comment: ECMP (Routing) STP (Swtiching) . The best if possible is to have small networks. Example you have a 192.168.0.1/24, you can divide that network into 4 or 6 just as an example. 192.168.0.0/26. By doing this you are going to provide more security by segmentation, better management even create firewall policies for this different networks. Having a big network can compromise all the computers, also bring latency because of the broadcast.

Comment: Real life example in 2003 a virus(Worm:W32/Slammer) attacked MSSQL was sending UDP broadcast packages. They where so many that it was able to shutdown the whole network. If you have segmentation that attack only affected the network the mssql was a member, second to mitigate you can turn down the router interface of that segment to eliminate the propagation and also to provide business continuity until you resolve the virus issue.